# Swift - Tab Bar Controller not showing when pushed

Tags: swift, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a series of views that are accessed via the Tab Bar Controller - they all behave and the Tab Bar is visible when each icon is pressed.

However when one of these views pushes to another the Tab Bar does not show.

I have tried forcing the Tab Bar with both:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, your tab bar controller is a child of a `UINavigationController`, you tried to push another view controller onto this navigation controller and the tab bar is not showing?

Comment: Can you explain better how is your hierarchy?

Comment: @RicoCrescenzio UINavigationController -> UITabBarController -> UIViewController (call it V1), where "->" means "parent of". And while you're in V1, you tried to push another view controller V2 onto the navigation controller. Is that accurate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your hierarchy (but I could be wrong, it's not 100% clear what you said), it's a normal behaviour because the new view controller `V2` entirely replace the current view which is the `UITabBarController`, not the `V1`. Your hierarchy is maybe something like this

```
UINavigationController
          |
          |
          UITabBarController ----> VC2
                 |
                 |
                VC1
```

The vc1 is *embedded* in the tab bar controller. So when you push the `VC2` is shown and the whole `UITabBarController` is hidden.

You should do something like this

```
UITabBarController
       |
       |
       UINavigationController
               |
               |
               VC1 ------> VC2
```